# Quelles sont les différences entre les mots "appartenir", "posséder" et "détenir" ?

Tags: droit-et-justice, définition

Dans l'[Arrêté du 2 août 2022 portant application des articles L. 562-2 et suivants du code monétaire et financier](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jorf/id/JORFTEXT000046160760), il est indiqué que:

*[...] qui appartiennent à, sont possédés, détenus [...]*

Quelles sont les différences entre ces mots ? Dans un langage "courant, je les utiliserai sans distinction, mais leur usage ici semble indiquer qu'ils ont une signification bien particulière.

PS: Est-ce que cette question devrait se trouver sur law SE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans le vocabulaire courant, il n'y a pas de différence de sens entre « X appartient à A », « A possède X », « A est le propriétaire de X » et « X est la propriété de A ». En revanche, « A détient X » n'est pas forcément synonyme : « A détient X » signifie que A a le contrôle effectif de X sans forcément en être le propriétaire. Un voleur peut *détenir* l'objet volé, un gestionnaire peut *détenir* l'objet confié, mais aucun des deux ne le *possède*. Étrangement, « A est en possession de X » est synonyme de « A détient X » et non de « A possède X ».

Pour ce qui est du vocabulaire juridique, le *Dictionnaire juridique* de Serge Braudo confirme que [détention](https://www.dictionnaire-juridique.com/definition/detention.php) a les mêmes nuances que son sens courant (un détenteur peut être locataire, dépositaire, mandataire, etc.). Pour ce qui est de la *[possession](https://www.dictionnaire-juridique.com/definition/possession.php)*, il y a une nuance avec la *[propriété](https://www.dictionnaire-juridique.com/definition/propriete.php) qui n'existe pas dans le langage courant. La *possession* est le fait de se conduire en propriétaire en pensant de bonne foi l'être. On peut donc être possesseur sans être propriétaire, même si c'est rare.

Je ne trouve pas de définition juridique du verbe *appartenir* (mais je n'ai pas cherché longtemps). Je pense que « X appartient à A » signifie « A est le propriétaire de X », alors que « X est possédé par A » signifie « A est le possesseur de X ». Ceci expliquerait l'utilisation des trois verbes, qui ne sont donc pas équivalents dans tous les cas.

Comment: Je trouve pas ça « rare » comme par exemple quand tu fais l'épicerie avant d'être passé à la caisse, ou différemment lors d'une vente quand il y a transfert immédiat de propriété mais que le bien n'est pas encore livré, le vendeur est toujours en possession. [Crépeau](https://nimbus.mcgill.ca/pld-ddp/dictionary/show/43334) est aussi utile pour ce genre de question si ça t'intéresse...

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait les traduire comme ceci :

> *appartenir à* (fr) : *belong to* (en)
> *être possédé par* (fr) : *to be owned by*
> *être détenu par* (fr) : *to be held/detained by*

D'abord, l'utilisation de la forme passive en français est beaucoup moins fréquente qu'en anglais, donc la plupart du temps on utiliserait *appartenir à*, si on parlait de l'objet plutôt que de son propriétaire:

> *Ce livre m'appartient.* <-> *Je possède ce livre.*

En outre, *posséder* est un mot un peu soutenu, par exemple, plus logique pour un bien immobilier que pour un objet de la vie quotidienne. Comparer :

> *J'ai un livre / une maison.* (I have a book/house.)
> *Je possède un livre /une maison.*

Finalement, *détenir* évoque la force (d'ailleurs, le nom *détenu* signifie *prisoner/inmate*).

On peu aussi utiliser *tenir* dans le sens de *détenir*, comme dans [*On le tient* dans cette blague de Gorafi](https://www.legorafi.fr/2019/07/22/lindividu-qui-construisait-des-ronds-points-partout-en-france-enfin-arrete/). Ici *on le tient* est un équivalent du fameux [*We got him.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_got_him)

Comment: *Détenir* n'évoque pas particulièrement la force. Il y a une nuance avec *posséder*, mais ce n'est pas lié à la force : *détenir* signifie qu'on a le contrôle physique de l'objet (par exemple on l'a entre les mains, ou on le conserve chez soi), sans forcément en être le propriétaire. Cela ne suggère pas la force : l'objet peut être confié, prêté...

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' merci pour cette precision. Je suis physicien à la base - pour moi *un control physique* sous-entend une force ;)